# Survey data stata code corresponding sas code?

Tags: sas, stata

I have 2 questions for survey data:

1, What's the difference between **svy:tab** and  **svy,subpop(XX): tab**? if subgroup first then use **svy:tab**.

2, Do we have the corresponding **SAS code** as **svy, subpop(XX): tab**?

Thanks in advance for your help and time.

Comment: A few pointers because you're new: You should just ask one question in a post. You should definitely go back and "accept" the answers you found most helpful to your previous posts -- this gives people an incentive to help you for your new questions. And finally, it's important to tell people what you've done to try to answer your own question... for example, have you read the Stata documentation for this command? What does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subpop() option means that estimates are only computed for a single subpopulation identified by XX not equal to 0 and not missing. For a simple binary XX variable, that would be equivalent to XX==1. The reason to use subpop() is that merely adding an "if XX==1" restriction will often fail at producing the  correct variance estimates for the subpopulation. However, if you're just looking at proportions with tab, that should not make a difference since these are point estimates. You can find more details (including formulas) [here](http://www.agecon.ksu.edu/support/Stata11Manual/svy.pdf). I am not sure what the equivalent SAS code is.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful. BTW, the corresponding SAS code for that one is adding **domain** in **PROC SURVEYFREQ**. It should work but I haven't tried till now.